# Android Studio Intelij при старте грузит проц

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте, до этого пользовался Eclips + плагин Андроидовский . Сейчас решил поставить Android Studio от IntleliJ. Поставил. При запуске ноуту аж плохо стало, резкий скачок процессор на 100%. Это длится около минуты иногда больше, когда идет индексирование и так далее. Иногда потом еще во время работы скачки есть. ОС - Debian LXDE. Laptop - Fujitsu AH552 (core i7, 8gb RAM ).

При запуске эклипса такого никогда не был. Что это так грузи и можно ли его как-то угомонить?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/android.html попробуйте вот это установить. Возможно jetbrains уже поправили баг. По крайней мере про баг с деплоем я краем уха слышал, но у меня такого нет. И кстати советуют убирать галку auto-import у gradle, т.к. это увеличивает время загрузки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно такая же проблема была. Но у меня оперативку съедал всю. После эклипс крайне непривычно, вообще все по другому. Попробуйте создать проект под последнюю версию андроида, и пусть прогрузится полностью. Так же обновите среду. И приготовьтесь к тому, что грейдл будет по-долгу грузиться перед деплоем на девайс апкшника. У меня решилось тем, что после обновления эклипс я психанул ( проект перестал работать), и я выдержал все загрузки/подгрузки/обновления studio. Тем не менее, сейчас когда запускаю в начале дня среду, она грузится минуты 2 или если новый проект открываю. Кстати ноут у меня послабее вашего будет(i3,4Gb RAM).
Желаю терпения

Answer (score 3):

Отключил автообновления и выставил для грандла 'Offline work' в 'Project settings' (что именно из них помогло в принципе не проверял) - жить стало легче. А 'Auto import' по умолчанию и не стоит...
А обновить/подгрузить можно и вручную, когда появляется очевидная необходимость.
Хотя таких больших проблем и не испытывал, но несколько напрягало (Core i5, 16Gb RAM)